# TimeBounds won't execute?

Tags: java-sdk

I struggle using the timebounds option for an operation.

Use case : I want a transaction to be executed at a precise time, not before, not after.

I'm doing my tests on the test network.
The transaction occured when I don't set a timeBounds, but when I do I get the same result without (except that my tokens aren't sent).

Here's the code I use :

```
String timeBounds = "1534239756";
TimeBounds timeBoundsT = new TimeBounds(Long.parseLong(timeBounds), 0);

transaction = new Transaction.Builder(sourceAccount)
        .addOperation(new PaymentOperation.Builder(destination,
            new AssetTypeCreditAlphaNum12(assetName, issuer), amount).build())
        .addTimeBounds(timeBoundsT).addMemo(Memo.text("Memo")).build();


// Sign the transaction to prove you are actually the person sending it.
transaction.sign(distributor);

// And finally, send it off to Stellar!
SubmitTransactionResponse response = null;
try {
  response = server.submitTransaction(transaction);
  System.out.println("Success!");
  System.out.println(response);
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Here's my response :

> Success!
>
> org.stellar.sdk.responses.SubmitTransactionResponse@3deb2326

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd like a transaction executed at a precise time, you need to submit it at that time.

The unix timestamp `1534239756` is in the past at the time you wrote this question (by about 10 minutes?). I suspect the transaction was successful.

To be certain, you should check the ResultXDR from the result.

```
response = server.submitTransaction(transaction);
System.out.println(response.getResultXdr());
```

Inspect that value in the [lab](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#xdr-viewer?type=TransactionResult&network=test).

Comment: So you can't prepar transactions to execute at a certain time? I get "result: [txTooEarly]" when the transaction is done before the timeBounds, which is correct. Is there any possibilities to lock the distributor account until a precise time?

Answer (score 2):

Timebounds only tell the system when a transaction should be valid, it does nothing to submit things at a certain time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm implementing a service to execute timed transactions at the right time.
Have a look here for the testnet version: https://test.artspirit.com/

Let me know if this would solve your usecase.